# Combining the same numbers with "and"

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, and-and

If I wanted to combine these two sentences with *and*.  *There are five documents on the table. There are five pens on the table.*
Might I say *There are **five** documents and pens on the table*? Would the first *five* here represent the second so that I would not need to say *five* twice?

Comment: It does. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Note that it seems to be a polarizing question, with different people having strong feelings about it meaning five in total or five of each … The short answer is that you should combine the two in a way that isn't so open to interpretation. Most often, saying *five* twice would make it clear. A more awkward phrasing, at least in this specific context, could be something like this following: *There are five **each** of documents and pens on the table.* That doesn't sound normal, but the meaning is understood.